# Ibanez SA160FML G & B String Warble/Oscillation Issue

Tags: guitar, strings

So i recently purchased an SA160FML. My guitar shop had a brand new piece because no one wanted a lefty but it was an old stock since this guitar is now discontinued.

I checked it at the shop and everything was fine with it. However, when i brought it home and used massive amounts of distortion, I definitely heard something wrong. I took it back in for set-up which included;

```
1) Truss Rod Adjustment
2) Saddle Adjustment
3) Intonation
4) New Strings
```

After the set-up the problem was still there. I've attached a link to 2 recordings,

```
1) My Strat on the same amp as the Ibanez with the same preset but sounds normal
2) My Ibanez on the same amp as the Strat with the same preset but has Warble/Oscillation
```

What I've tried to do to solve this;

```
1)Changed string set again
2)I can't lower the neck and middle pick up since they are direct mounted (The G&B string pups are 
  higher than the others)
3) Got the guitar set up again
4) Tried different amps
5) raised the bridge so that the strings will be further away from the pups (doesnt really help since 
   when i fret 12-22, they still sit very close to the pups)
```

I've currently ordered myself a cheap pair of bar magnet pickups to check if this will solve the issue. Most posts I see are dated to 2005 and back. Can anyone help me solve this issue? my shop isnt willing to give a refund as they see nothing wrong with the guitar.

```
Recordings:
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MWVYNiWjORjp5WVyOVtbgn_dgpf2sMkT

Comment: Is it with any pup - as Ibanez has humbucker, whereas Strat probably has single coil?

Comment: What you describe does indeed sound like the magnets are too close to the strings… with neither of them really being adjustable your test of different pickups might just work.

Comment: @Tim my Ibanez is HSS, the sound is present on the humbucker as well but I'm thinking thats because the neck or middle pickups are interfering?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've ordered a single hot rail pickup to replace to staggered ones INF ones that came with the Ibanez, I'm really hoping that solves my issue since I find it completely unplayable!

Comment: Height should be adjustable even on the direct mounted pickups, they should have springs or pieces of foam under them which are compressible - turning the mounting screws should result in raising or lowering the pickups. Are they already all the way down?

Comment: I noticed you played a high Bb on the Ibanez but a G on the Strat, both on the G string I assume. I’m guessing this only happens in the upper register. I agree magnetic interference is likely the cause but before you start putting in new pickups, follow @dwizum’s advice, take the strings off and check under the hood. It’s possible there’s foam under the pickups that might be hard and fully compacted and preventing the pickup from going down to the proper height.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Okay so what I just did was lower the pickups to their max, What I do Notice is that no matter what direction I move the screws the Pickups barely move a cm, so it could definitely be possible that the foam is extremely stiff. Raising the action really high for the G helped a bit but I'm still getting that major note difference. So I guess my next step is to take off the Pick Ups completely to see if the foam is stiff or something wrong with the spring!

Comment: The threads on pickup mounting screws are often very fine pitch, you may only get half a mm of height difference per complete turn of the screw. It may take several revolutions to make a noticeable difference. But yes, taking the pickups off will help you understand what's going on. Sometimes you can cut the foam or spring(s) down to get a lower adjustment range, too.

Comment: @dwizum Is right, those screws have very fine threads and barely change with a turn. Take care not to put too much pressure if you feel resistance on the screwdriver and strip the heads, it’s easy to do with screws that small. If you do feel resistance you’ll definitely have to take a look underneath. Keep us posted.

Comment: It just occurred to me it is also possible that the holes the screws go into are stripped. There are some fairly easy fixes for this though.

Comment: So Dwizum and John, I loosened my strings and took off the pickups, they both do infact have foam underneath. I screwed them back on however this time, I pushed the pickup in so the foam would shrink and then screwed it in that same position and they are now exactly 0.5mm from the G string while I fret at the 22nd fret which is exactly like my strat. This did somewhat solve the issue, however, the warbling is still slightly there and a lot more prominent on the B string as well now! any thoughts?

Comment: I couldn't hear the oscillation on the first recording by definitely on the second and it sounds a little like a mechanical rattle.  You said it was fine at the store and the difference is now massive amounts of distortion.  Does the problem persist with a clean sound?